# Accessing Spring Bean Attributes in a Java Command Line Application

Tags: spring, code-injection

I'm adding functionality to a Java/Spring web application so it can be run from the command line. In my main class I'd like to access multiple Beans I've defined in my Application Context File so i thought i could use the following init() method:

```
public void init() {            
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }
```

When i try access my injected bean called "properties" i get an exception in the following code because the bean is null:

```
private void loadConfigProperties() {
        String methodName = "loadConfigProperties";
        try {               
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFilePath));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            LOGGER.error(methodName,"", "IOException occured parsing config.properties File : " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
        parseConfigPropertiesFromLoadedFile();
    }
```

Is there any way to easily get multiple beans from the Application Context File if i'm using the inject annotation e.g `@Inject private Properties properties;`?